# Trying to make a http post request and expecting response by sending a json data using VB script

Tags: httprequest

we have a dashboard and it has credentials to login through.... created a json using vb script and written a simple code to post the json through a http request and trying to get response using GUI testing in UFT... please help me to get the respose text code below...
please tell me if i am missing something

```
   Dim fso, outFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Automation\output.txt", True,True)
    set json = CreateObject64("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject")

    index = -1

    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"runnerId","ebd1e5e79c")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"environmentId","966c-7a9fd2d9e003")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"name","Smoketest")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"started","12-18-202006:03:03")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"elapsedTime","01:06:05")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"success","passed")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"scenarios","Createtest")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"step","teststep1")

    json.EmitCompact = 0
    outFile.WriteLine(json.Emit())


    Dim objXmlHttpMain , URL

    URL="http://10.229.49.101/" 
    Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    on error resume next 
    objXmlHttpMain.open "POST",URL, False
    objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 

    objXmlHttpMain.send outFile

    sHTTPResponse = objXmlHttpMain.responseText

    msgbox sHTTPResponse

    set objJSONDoc = nothing 
    set objResult = nothing
    outFile.Close
    Set outFile=nothing
    set json=nothing
    Set fso=nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It has worked.

create a json file using code like below and using chilkat objects

Dim fso, outFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Automation\output.txt", True,True)
    set json = CreateObject64("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject")

    index = -1

    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"runnerId","1")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"environmentId","23")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"name","Smoketest")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"started","12-18-202006:03:03")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"elapsedTime","01:06:05")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"success","passed")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"scenarios","Createtest")
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"step","teststep1")

    json.EmitCompact = 0
    outFile.WriteLine(json.Emit())
    outFile.close
 
and later do a http post request like below,

Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(path,1)
    strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    dim objHTTP
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL="http://"   
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objHTTP.send strFileText
    If objHTTP.status = 200 Then
        msgbox "RESPONSE : " & objHTTP.responseText 
        HTTPRequest=objHTTP.responseText        
    else
        msgbox "ERRCODE : " & objHTTP.responseText
        HTTPRequest=objHTTP.responseText    
    End If
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing
```